# hover over tooltip? cant get it to work with a list in a top navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have been using W3schools to figure this out but i cant see what i have done wrong?

I have added the  text to the image icons in the top left which is what i want to appear as a tooltip when hovered over. I have only tried to style the first one (location tooltip) but i can't for the life of me figure out where i have gone wrong. An explanation would be great because as far as i can see it should work?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Top NAVBAR */

.topbar {
  background-color: #17D8C7;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}

.topbar nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.topbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topbar ul li img {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topright span {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topbar a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.topbar a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.location-pin {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.location-pin .locationtooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.location-pin .locationtooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.location-pin:hover .locationtooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Complete Suites</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="topbar">
    <nav>
      <ul class="topleft">
        <li class="location-pin">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/6t7njymhx/location-pin.png" alt="Location Pin"></a>
        </li>
        <span class="locationtooltiptext">EN11 0LB</span>
        <li class="contact-email">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Contact Email"></a>
        </li>
        <span class="emailtooltiptext">contact@completesuites.co.uk</span>
        <li class="open-time">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/fbh3oalat/open-time.png" alt="Opening Times"></a>
        </li>
        <span class="timetooltiptext">8:30 - 16:00</span>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topmiddle">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Email Promotions Sign Up"><span>Email Promotions</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topright">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a><span>|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a><span>|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I think i have managed to work out where i went wrong, i hadn't put the <span> tag inside the <a> tag? is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
.location-pin .locationtooltiptext
```

with

```
.location-pin + .locationtooltiptext
```

Also, all the other instances.

**Explanation:**

The selector `.location-pin .locationtooltiptext` means element with class `.locationtooltiptext` which **in** `.location-pin`.

You want `.locationtooltiptext` which is just next to `.location-pin` you need the selector `.location-pin + .locationtooltiptext`

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors</sup>

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Top NAVBAR */

.topbar {
  background-color: #17D8C7;
  height: 35px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}

.topbar nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.topbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topbar ul li img {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topright span {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topbar a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.topbar a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.location-pin {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.location-pin .locationtooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.location-pin .locationtooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.location-pin:hover .locationtooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Complete Suites</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="topbar">
    <nav>
      <ul class="topleft">
        <li class="location-pin">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/6t7njymhx/location-pin.png" alt="Location Pin"></a>
          <span class="locationtooltiptext">EN11 0LB</span>
        </li>
        <li class="contact-email">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Contact Email"></a>
        </li>
        <span class="emailtooltiptext">contact@completesuites.co.uk</span>
        <li class="open-time">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/fbh3oalat/open-time.png" alt="Opening Times"></a>
        </li>
        <span class="timetooltiptext">8:30 - 16:00</span>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topmiddle">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Email Promotions Sign Up"><span>Email Promotions</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topright">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a><span>|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a><span>|</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah ok so i could also fix it by putting the <span> tag inside the <a> tag?

Comment: sorry what do you mean. 'the question is if the style will fit'?

Comment: also, is there any reason to do it either way? i mean to say which is the best method/practice?

Comment: The answer for the question is "yes, the style fit" :) You can see in my updated answer. If you want primitive usage for the tooltip, it will be better to put it in the link (`a`) so it will take his position relatively his "parent". The problem is that now, the tooltip is cut in the edge of the browser so you need more "clever" tooltip which require to put the tooltip DOM (in your case, the `.locationtooltiptext`) under the `body` and calculate the position.